# Visual Studio 2010 is timing out way too quickly on a website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

After setting breakpoints and trying to step through the code of a website, the debugger seems to "time out" within only a few seconds and stops debugging. I have no idea what is causing this and it is driving me insane.

Here is the code I am trying to step through:

```
 using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
        {

            // Create new customer.
            CustomersBLL customerOperations = new CustomersBLL();
            customerOperations.InsertCustomer(quote.CurrentDate, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            // Prepare to insert Quote.
            // Retrieve CustomerID. 
            Table = customerOperations.GetNewestCustomerID();
            quote.CustomerID = (int)Table.Rows[0][0];

            // Get word count and quote amount.
            quote.GetWordCount();
            quote.GetQuoteAmount();

            // Insert Quote

            // Insert DocumentFile - must retrieve QuoteNumber.

            transaction.Complete();
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to help with so little information. Web Forms? MVC? SilverLight? Which .NET version? Web Site or Web Application Project? Etc.?

Comment: .NET 4, ASP.NET Web Site, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a clean, new web site, or is it specific to your current code?

Comment: It only seems to be occuring within this project.

Comment: Might it have something to do with the code being inside a <script> tab on a aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely means that your web application is reset, either due to an unhandled exception or to recycling parameters set on the application pool in IIS.

The first thing to do is check the Windows Application and System Event logs to see if unhandled exceptions are being reported.

The second thing to do is check your IIS app pool settings to see if there is a short recycle limit that may be met.

Comment: I am sorry, but are you referring to the Windows Application Event Log or is this something within Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry: you should check the windows application and system event logs.

Comment: In the System event log I am receiving this messasge: A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '2836'. The data field contains the error number.

Answer (score 0):

Does it stop debugging because the application has finished its life cycle?

My guess would be that your breakpoints aren't even being met because they are in code that isn't executed.  But without seeing more code and details (i.e. where the breakpoint(s) are/is) then it is just pure guessing.

Do you receive any errors or does it just silently stop?

Comment: No, the application has not finished its life cycle. I can step through the code very quickly and even obtain data by hovering the mouse over variables, but if I pause for more than a few seconds it just stops. I have to keep hitting F10/F11 fairly quickly to keep it going. I don't receive any errors, it just stops debugging.

Comment: I have added the code that I am trying to step through at the top of this post. I have been setting breakpoints on the first couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you website is hosted in IIS and you are doing a debugger attach. My guess is that the application pool is expiring the worker thread.

Got into IIS, find the application pool / right click Set Application Pool Defaults.

```
Ping Enabled: false
```

Comment: I should set Ping Enabled to false? If I do that then I thought that the Ping maximum response value did not matter.

Comment: Yes, set to false. Yes, I think you are right. Do not need to set Max Response. Answer updated.